# How Prevent a book from being downloaded by restricting IP?

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, ip

I would like to restrict from being downloaded a digital book by someone who did not buy it. Is there a way to do it?

When the user buys the book, it is sent to him a link from where he can download it, but he is the only person that can read it and can´t share it. Likely, only his IP is allowed to read this book.

Comment: My IP address changes fairly regularly, especially when on mobile. This is not a good idea.

Comment: Not just IP is changing, someone in same buliding  may share the same IP.  You can add login Function,and check the user each time  before download.

Comment: How are you doing it? Need more data to understand.